# in_array problem

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a couple of big arrays with numbers as items, each one has 5 000 - 10 000 values.

All are the simple arrays, like

`$array = array(125,345345,345,3485,324,65,746647,3221, ... );`

I'm trying to search them for some number, and repeat this operation nearly 1 000 times for different numbers.

Like

```
if $array has item 345 {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

But the request takes a long time to finish. Sometimes server gives a timeout error.

What is the best way to search for some number in simple by structure, but big by their size arrays?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458242/alternatives-to-php-in-array-for-large-arrays-for-avoiding-duplicates-entries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing is to flip the array around (see `array_flip`) and use `isset($array[$key])`. That uses a hash lookup instead of a search, so it's much faster.

Other than that, try using a database or some more optimal way of dealing with large datasets.

Comment: seems I can add a number as a key and then check by isset?

Comment: @Rooney, yes. I'm not sure how you are building your array. If it's hard coded, using `array_flip` is handy. `$a = array_flip(array(1,20,35,...))`. Otherwise, if you build it at run time, you can just do `$a[$id] = true`. The value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (in_array(345, $array)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

didn't see that you wanted to do this 1000 times per number.
use a database.

Use a db like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE number={$number}", $link);
$x = (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0  ? mysql_num_rows($result) : false );
```

Comment: Simplified: `return in_array(345, $array);`

Comment: 1k times for 1k different numbers

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a computer science problem than a PHP one.  I would recommend looking into "binary search" or "binary trees".  If you google around, you might even find an existing implementation.